# How to reduce warmup time of query result cache when your query is like "q=*:*"?

Tags: solr

Our solr index contains ~10,00,000 documents. We do bulk updates every 2 hours. After each bulk update, when the new searcher is warmed up, we see a peak in our response time. This is due to Query Result cache warmup which takes ~40 seconds warmup time and which is too much. Also, the hit ratio for query result cache is very small, i.e. ~7% only.

Our configuration in solrconfig.xml is like this :-

For new searcher :-

```
<listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
  <arr name="queries">
    <lst>
        <str name="q">*:*</str>
        ...
        ...
    </lst>
  </arr>
</listener>
```

For query result cache :-

```
<queryResultCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                     size="10000"
                     initialSize="512"
                     autowarmCount="128"/>
```

We have tried tuning our query result cache by changing cache `size`, `initialSize` and `autowarmCount`, but got no reduction in warmup time (though hit ratio gets slightly increased to ~9%) .

**Can anyone please suggest a way to reduce the warmup time of query result cache with such configurations ?**

Comment: So what is the goal of having `*:*` as your warm up query? The warmup time is related to what you want to achieve - if you want to perform less work, then it's necessary to look at why you're doing the work you're doing instead, and drop as much of that as possible. Do you even need the `*:*` warmup query? The query result cache will depend on what your queries look like, so you'll have to optimize your queries to increase cachability to get better results.

Comment: @MatsLindh When I started working on optimization, I had the same question in mind, i.e., why use caching for `*:*` . So I removed the query result cache configuration altogether, but that resulted in 50 ms increase in response time. So removing the `*:*` warmup query isn't an option. Will have to go with that only.

Comment: Then that's the fact - you're trading 40 second bootup time for 50ms lower query times for the response time. It's important to know that this is at startup - as the queries start coming in you should see the query time normalize as most of the data is in the disk cache already. Also, increasing your cachability to get better ache hit ratio and run more of them for autowarming (instead of the 128) should mitigate part of the necessity for the large autowarming query.